# Github Actions hides URL's from aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions, aws-cli

We're using Github Actions to realize our CI/CD pipeline in AWS ELB. One of our workflows is requesting logs with commands "aws elasticbeanstalk request-environment-info" and "[aws elasticbeanstalk retrieve-environment-info](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/retrieve-environment-info.html)". The problem is when the Github agent gets info from AWS it hides the URL for getting logs in AWS.

```
name: Request logs
env: 
  EB_PACKAGE_S3_BUCKET_NAME : "s3bucket" 
  EB_APPLICATION_NAME       : "appname"
  AWS_REGION_NAME           : "us-east-2"

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment_name:
        type: choice
        description: Select the environment to get logs from
        required: true
        options:
          - app-dev
          - app-prod
      info_type:
        type: choice
        description: 100 last lines (tail) or full log (bundle)
        required: true
        options:
          - "tail"
          - "bundle"

jobs:
  RequestLogs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Configure my AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id    :  ${{ secrets.MY_AWS_ACCES_KEY }}
        aws-secret-access-key:  ${{ secrets.MY_AWS_SECRET_KEY }}
        aws-region           :  ${{ env.AWS_REGION_NAME }}

    - name: Request logs
      run : |
        aws elasticbeanstalk request-environment-info \
        --environment-name ${{ github.event.inputs.environment_name }} \
        --info-type ${{ github.event.inputs.info_type }}
    - name: Sleep for 30 seconds
      uses: jakejarvis/wait-action@master
      with:
        time: '30s'

    - name: Retrieve logs
      run : |
        aws elasticbeanstalk retrieve-environment-info \
        --environment-name ${{ github.event.inputs.environment_name }} \
        --info-type ${{ github.event.inputs.info_type }}
```

Expected response:

```
"EnvironmentInfo": [

        {
            "InfoType": "tail",
            "Ec2InstanceId": "intanceid",
            "SampleTimestamp": "date and time",
            "Message": "https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-123456789.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/resources/environments/logs/someHeaders"
        }
```

Real response:

```
"EnvironmentInfo": [
        {
            "InfoType": "tail",
            "Ec2InstanceId": "intanceid",
            "SampleTimestamp": "date and time",
            "Message": "https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-*******.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/resources/environments/logs/someHeaders"
        }
```

Github agent think that that numbers (https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-**123456789**) is secret and hide it (https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-*******), but we don't have such secret in Github settings. How we can see full URL?

Comment: Could you share your whole Github Actions workflow in the question?

Comment: After reading the aws doc, I didn't get what represent the part which appear as *** (which should have 123456789). But for Github Actions to hide it, it's possible that it's related to the secrets you used to configure aws in your workflow before requesting / retrieving the environment infos.

Comment: Do you have your AWS account ID set as a secret in GitHub actions?

Comment: @mpriscella yes

Comment: @GuiFalourd as I understand, that numbers means unique ID of app environment in AWS. It’s doesn’t changed while I make tests in command line on my laptop and I don’t have such secrets on GitHub

Comment: On the [aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_RetrieveEnvironmentInfo.html) the sample response doesn't return any id with this format. The only value that looks similar is the "Expired" field. Did you find a example somewhere about this env id format?

Comment: @GuiFalourd No, it's my guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your AWS Account ID is set as a Secret, GitHub will automatically redact that string of text anywhere it’s found in the Action logs. More info, as well as some methods of getting around it, can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets).

Edit:

The action `aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials` masks the Account ID by default. You can unmask it by passing the parameter `mask-aws-account-id: false` to the action. Here's a [link](https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/blob/v1.6.1/action.yml#L25) to the relevant part of the schema.

Comment: I don't have such a Secret in repository settings.

Comment: Oh sorry, in your response to my last comment you indicated that you did. In that case GitHub may be redacting automatically based on it recognizing that it's an AWS resource URL and that Account IDs are typically kept secret, but I can't find documentation confirming that.

Comment: Ah nevermind, the issue is that the action you're using `aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials` masks the account ID automatically. You can pass in a param `mask-aws-account-id: false` to the action and that should work. https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials/blob/master/action.yml#L25

Comment: thank you, it works. Why they didn't mention it in the documentation ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mpriscella

The answer is: aws configure credentials automatically hide your Account ID (and maybe other).

There is the way to show it - add param **mask-aws-account-id: no** (or as mansioned @mpriscella **false** instead no):

```
steps:
    - name: Configure my AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id    :  ${{ secrets.MY_AWS_ACCES_KEY }}
        aws-secret-access-key:  ${{ secrets.MY_AWS_SECRET_KEY }}
        aws-region           :  ${{ env.AWS_REGION_NAME }}
        mask-aws-account-id  : no
```